# Will a dragon jumping out of a frozen lake make all people standing on the ice fall into the lake?

Tags: dragons, ice

To shorten the explanation, physics-wise I'm writing scene that is similar to the one you could see in Skyrim Dawnguard; a dragon jumps out of frozen lake shattering the ice. In the game he creates the hole and nothing happens to the remaining ice on the lake.
You can see it here https://youtu.be/2b2GDtdN144?t=21

How real is this? Would the ice crack and the hero on it fall down?

Ice can be as thick as you like, and the hero's distance from the hole can be let's say up to 50 meters.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your dragon as big and heavy as the one in skyrim or is it different?

Comment: @Tortliena it's not a dragon, but let's say it has similar mass

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ice crack? Probably not.

Hero fall? Absolutely.

Let's do some (heavily ballparked) math. Let's assume the lake is frozen at least 10 inches, which is twice that for a human, but it's also the prescribed minimum for a car and seeing as there's a dragon, let's give it the benefit of the doubt and assume a minimum of 10 inches. The dragon seems to be creating holes about 10' in diameter (again, that's just a conservative estimate).

How much force does it take to shatter ice? Unclear, but we can ballpark it. Using [this table](https://pubs.usgs.gov/wri/wri024158/wri024158_files/w024158p33_48.pdf), we can determine it gets crushed at around 400 pounds per square inch. Now, obviously, not *all* the ice here is shattered, but judging from the graphics, I'd say at least a quarter of the mass from any given eruption point has disappeared, so that's around 2900 destroyed square inches of ice, so that's around 5,000,000 Newtons.

How much is that? Well, it's about 40% of the thrust from a Space Shuttle solid booster *at liftoff*. Surprisingly, this doesn't shatter the lake because of how concentrated the force is so the ice is cleanly broken and the force doesn't transfer. Not to mention that even though cracks will start appearing in the lake, the floes won't shatter into small enough pieces because of how thick the ice is. You will still probably get tossed like a ragdoll from the shockwave, though.

Comment: What if the dragon first melts the ice to the proper diameter to exit?!

Comment: Then no shattering blow, no shockwave, no tossed-like-a-ragdoll hero. If I were the hero I'd be plenty frightened, though.

Comment: @Xi'anнівійні Interestingly enough, my ballpark calculations did not end up with [nuclear winter](https://www.reddit.com/r/Shadowrun/comments/1napj6/everyone_is_dead_san_francisco_is_a_radioactive/). In order to melt 25cm of ice in 3m diameter from -5°C one only needs energy of around 130 kg of TNT. You can check on youtube how such a breath attack could look like. Don't forget your horse when fighting a creature capable of this!